# Konva errors/warnings in Firefox console

Tags: javascript, firefox, konvajs

I am getting an error message in the Firefox console for the simplest possible Konva demo. The HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@4.1.0/konva.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Konva Warning Demo</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container"style="width: 800px;height: 600px;" ></div>

    <script>
      var stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 3000,
        height: 3000,
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

gives me this set of messages in the console:

```
Expected declaration but found ‘[’.  Skipped to next declaration. 3 konvatest.html
Error in parsing value for ‘width’.  Declaration dropped. konvatest.html
Error in parsing value for ‘height’.  Declaration dropped. konvatest.html
```

It doesn't give me line numbers, but I'm concerned that the values for width and height may not be getting set. And I don't understand the issue with '[' at all.

If I comment out the declaration of Konva.Stage, the messages go away.

Is this a non-issue or just a peculiarity of Firefox? Or is it something I might be doing wrong in the declaration?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any issues with the code. it should work well. And I don't see such errors in Firefox. Probably you can just ignore them.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting that you don't see those errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put space between "container"style.
2. Make sure your script is executed after konva is loaded -- your unpkg link seems to be slow and replacing it by reference to a local copy helped.
3. To fulfill 2. consider, instead of inline script,
   to use

```
       <body><div id="containeer"></div><script src="... konva"><script src="yourscript.js">
```

4. (specify the language of the script)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've implemented them all and still get the same messages.